# Interactive Graph in Qt

Tags: qt, graph, interactive

I want to make interactive graph like this using Qt and C++ : http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Cubic_spline_interpolation

Any leads on how to do that ?

EDIT :
Okay, I've already tried my hands on the QGraphicsView class and qwt library. However, I find no easy way to introduce interactive-ness. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the [QGraphicsview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html) framework and the [diagram](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) example

Comment: Okay, I did NOT see the diagram example and it does seem helpful. I'll work on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aakashbhowmick - there may be a lib to plot splines directly, but if you are more interested in learning Qt then QGraphicsview is the place

Comment: The link of `diagram` is invalid now. New link is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html